# Telenor easypay with nop commerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

**Introduction :**
I am working with the open source nop commerce project. I needed to implement telenor easypay (payment gateway) along with others.

**Problem :**
The plugins for the opencart, wordpress and prestashop are available but unfortunately not for nop-commerce.

**Question :** One option is to use open api but is there any other way i should look into or follow? What is the best solution right now?

If anyone have idea or experience with that, please do help. Thanks for your time.